# Android: does finish() include an inherent return?

Tags: android

I have an app that calls startActivityForResult to start a second activity. The second activity has a method called when a button is pressed, which calls setResult() and then finish() if a particular condition is met, but if it is not, then it does some additional processing.

In other words:

```
public void clickOK(View V) {
    if (someBooleanCondition)
    {
        setResult(resultOne);
        finish();
    }
    setResult(resultTwo);
    finish();
}
```

Do I need to have return after the finish() in the first if block, or does finish() act as if there is an inherent return statement there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep your code you will have to call return after the `finish()` inside the `if`, because the method will be executed to the end.

Better you change your method to this:

```
public void clickOK(View V) {
    if (someBooleanCondition)
    {
        setResult(resultOne);
        finish();
    } else {
        setResult(resultTwo);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that that code is "better", but the long and short of it is that `finish();` doesn't cause the rest of the method to stop executing. So you can either put an explicit `return;` statement after your `finish();`, or you could use an `else` block like you suggested. Either way works.